# Delphi - How to keep doing queries after closing the android app?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I'm working on a project. The project contains a service. This service processes queries at a MySQL database and shows the user a notification that depends on the result of the query. But the query stops when I close the main app. How can I keep doing the queries even if the main app is closed? (Like chat apps you know)

PS: Queries and notifications codes are placed in service and queries are made with the PPL (Parallel Programming Library)

PS: I don't think there is a problem with the code lines. I guess I need a triggering with the services for main app.

```
unit ComPhoneService1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  System.Android.Service,
  AndroidApi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
  Androidapi.JNI.Os, System.Notification, Data.DB, DBAccess, Uni, MemDS,
  UniProvider, MySQLUniProvider, System.IOUtils, System.Threading;

type
  TDM = class(TAndroidService)
    NotificationCenter1: TNotificationCenter;
    MySQLUniProvider1: TMySQLUniProvider;
    UniBaglanti: TUniConnection;
    UniQuery1: TUniQuery;
    function AndroidServiceStartCommand(const Sender: TObject;
      const Intent: JIntent; Flags, StartId: Integer): Integer;

    Procedure Sorgu;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  DM: TDM;

implementation

{%CLASSGROUP 'FMX.Controls.TControl'}

{$R *.dfm}
    uses
     AndroidAPI.JNI.APP;

Procedure TDM.Sorgu;
var
 ATask: ITask;
 IniFile: TStringList;
 Bildirim: TNotification;
begin
  ATask := TTask.Create(Procedure()
  var
   A: Boolean;
   begin
     A := False;
     Repeat
      begin
         Sleep(10000);
         if FileExists(TPath.GetPublicPath + '/pcid.ini', True) = True then
       begin
          try
           IniFile := TStringList.Create;
           IniFile.LoadFromFile(TPath.GetPublicPath + '/pcid.ini');

           UniQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select * from tblHareketler where PCID=:aydi and Goruldu=:Durum';
           UniQuery1.ParamByName('aydi').Value := Trim(IniFile.Text);
           UniQuery1.ParamByName('Durum').Value := 'Gorulmedi';
           UniQuery1.ExecSQL;
           UniQuery1.Open;

            if UniQuery1.RecordCount > 0 then
           begin
            Bildirim := NotificationCenter1.CreateNotification;
            Bildirim.AlertBody := 'Yeni eylemler mevcut! Görmek için lütfen tıklayınız';
            NotificationCenter1.PresentNotification(Bildirim);
           end;
          finally
            IniFile.Free;
          end;
       end;
      end;
     Until A = True;
   end);
   ATask.Start;
end;

function TDM.AndroidServiceStartCommand(const Sender: TObject;
  const Intent: JIntent; Flags, StartId: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Sorgu;
  Result := TJService.JavaClass.START_STICKY;
end;

end.
```

https://i.hizliresim.com/nOjO55.gif

Thanks already

Best Regards...

Comment: Please share your code in the post.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: As far as I can see, it shouldn't stop. Does it stop immediately after the app is closed, or some time after? Do you have any code in the app that might stop the service?

Comment: The query continues without closing the main application, returning to the main menu, but when the main application ends completely from the tabs section, the query stops and the notification is not sent.

In the main application only fservice.StartService command have and this is already just using it to start the service. There's no other code.

Comment: Please change TTask implementation of your logic to anonymous thread. It should work out of the box.

Comment: I added a GIF to my question. To better understand my problem.

Comment: The link to the .gif is broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unit ComPhoneService1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  System.Android.Service,
  AndroidApi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
  Androidapi.JNI.Os, System.Notification, Data.DB, DBAccess, Uni, MemDS,
  UniProvider, MySQLUniProvider, System.IOUtils, System.Threading;

type
  TDM = class(TAndroidService)
    NotificationCenter1: TNotificationCenter;
    MySQLUniProvider1: TMySQLUniProvider;
    UniBaglanti: TUniConnection;
    UniQuery1: TUniQuery;
    function AndroidServiceStartCommand(const Sender: TObject;
      const Intent: JIntent; Flags, StartId: Integer): Integer;

    Procedure Sorgu;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  DM: TDM;

implementation

{%CLASSGROUP 'FMX.Controls.TControl'}

{$R *.dfm}
    uses
     AndroidAPI.JNI.APP;

Procedure TDM.Sorgu;
var
 IniFile: TStringList;
 Bildirim: TNotification;
begin
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure()
  var
   A: Boolean;
   begin
     A := False;
     Repeat
      begin
         Sleep(10000);
         if FileExists(TPath.GetPublicPath + '/pcid.ini', True) = True then
       begin
          try
           IniFile := TStringList.Create;
           IniFile.LoadFromFile(TPath.GetPublicPath + '/pcid.ini');

           UniQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select * from tblHareketler where PCID=:aydi and Goruldu=:Durum';
           UniQuery1.ParamByName('aydi').Value := Trim(IniFile.Text);
           UniQuery1.ParamByName('Durum').Value := 'Gorulmedi';
           UniQuery1.ExecSQL;
           UniQuery1.Open;

            if UniQuery1.RecordCount > 0 then
           begin
            Bildirim := NotificationCenter1.CreateNotification;
            Bildirim.AlertBody := 'Yeni eylemler mevcut! Görmek için lütfen tıklayınız';
            NotificationCenter1.PresentNotification(Bildirim);
           end;
          finally
            IniFile.Free;
          end;
       end;
      end;
     Until A = True;
   end).Start;
end;

function TDM.AndroidServiceStartCommand(const Sender: TObject;
  const Intent: JIntent; Flags, StartId: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Sorgu;
  Result := TJService.JavaClass.START_STICKY;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I made changes like you said, but I was not successful. I've updated my issue to better understand the issue.